# merge values in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in which I have to merge values like this:

list: `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0]`

result: `[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]`

It merges from left to right, and only merges 2 of the same numbers per time.

> - the first two values are added up (1 + 1)
> - the 2 is shifted to the left
> - the other two values are added up as well (1 + 1) and shifted
> - the list is be padded from the right with zero's so the length of the list stays the same
> - (edit) any zero's in the list will be at the end, not in the middle

I'm quite new to Python, and don't have a clear idea on how to approach this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What should happen with an input like `[1, 0, 1, 0]`? Are you writing a 2048 clone? If so, you've made a good attempt at describing what you want to do, but your description still needs more precision.

Comment: Thanks, I already managed to move all the zero's in the middle to the right. So there won't be any zero's left in the middle. As for the 2048 clone, you're right :) thought it could be a good practise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something simple and straight-forward:

```
def merge_pairs(a):
    out = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(a):
        if i < len(a) - 1 and a[i] == a[i + 1]:
            out.append(a[i] + a[i + 1])
            i += 2
        else:
            out.append(a[i])
            i += 1
    out += [0] * (len(a) - len(out))
    return out
```

Not 100% sure this is what you require, but perhaps it can be a start.

The single test you provided seems to work:

```
>>> merge_pairs([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0])
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You've missed an edge case where `a[-1]` is unmerged and not 0.

Comment: @user2357112 Well spotted. How about now? :)

Comment: Now it's fixed. We may also need to consider how `0`s in the middle should affect the merge, but it's not clear how to do that. We'll know if the OP clarifies it.

Comment: @user2357112 True, the specification is not very clear. Also not clear if the same number is allowed to be merged more than once; I ignored that. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! and there won't be any zero's in the middle so this is sufficient.